# Curried function seems not typesafe with Typescript and ramda

Tags: typescript, types, ramda.js, currying

I have a function:

```
function myFunction(n: number, s: string, n2: number): boolean {
  throw ''
}
```

I partially call it using ramda 0.27.1:

```
const curriedStringNon = curry(myFunction)(123, 'string')
```

But then I missed some typesafety:

```
curriedStringNon(123) // <- this is allowed which is expected
curriedStringNon('string') // <- this errors as it should
curriedStringNon() // <- but why is this allowed?
```

I don't expect this to compile because `myFunction` cannot be called with only two args:

```
myFunction(123, 'string') // <- this also errors which is expected
```

Comment: Maybe open an issue on Ramda's typings?

Comment: From Ramda's point of view, that's not an error.  You just get back the function.  This has been a point of contention even among the core team, but I'd argue that it's the most logical behavior.

Comment: It actually shows a "Expected 1 arguments, but got 0" error - https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-with-ramda-forked-nqud1g . Check your version of Ramda and the `@types/ramda`.

Comment: I wrote [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70687948) several months ago that has some bearing on this.

Comment: @ScottSauyet - yup got it.  Thanks.  If you make an answer I can mark it as correct.

Comment: @OriDrori huh weird.  Maybe something to do with ramda 0.27 vs 0.28?

Comment: Might be, but it usually the types the have some differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments,

> From Ramda's point of view, that's not an error. You just get back the function. This has been a point of contention even among the core team, but I'd argue that it's the most logical behavior.

and

> I wrote [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70687948) several months ago that has some bearing on this.